# Set 3d object always back with Render Queue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, render, depth-buffer

I've added a cube object with position (0, 0, 0) and sphere object with position (0.5, 0, -3). I've added textures and materials.

[image: Settings]

I want to move the sphere behind of all other objects with render queue or different solution.

I've added this script on the sphere. It's not working:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class RenderQueueTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int renderQueuePosition = -1;
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.renderQueue = renderQueuePosition;
    }
}
```

I've also tried to change the sphere material render queue in the inspector.

Default render queue of the sphere material is: 2000

I changed it to: 1999

Doesn't work.

Here are the textures:

[image: Texture 1]

[image: Texture 2]

Comment: The sphere also needs to have a material that doesn't write to the depth buffer (`ZWrite Off`).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is try to move the sprite itself back, set the Transform position.y to -0.1 in the inspector or do it with a script like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SendBackScrpt: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 sendBack = new Vector3(0, -0.1f, 0);

    private void Start()
    {
       Vector3 prevPos = transform.position;
       transform.position = prevPos + sendBack;
    }
}
```

what you could also try is putting the sprite above the other one in the hierarchy.